# Samsung Smart TV App Installation

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, installation-package

We have been experimenting with Samsung Smart TV app.

Recently we built a prototype app to experiment with a certain feature but we are passing hard time to get it working over the real TV.

Even though it works perfectly over the Samsung emulator but almost no luck with the real tv.
FYI, We are using "UE32F5570" model for the testing purpose.

We setup a web server with "widgetlist.xml" and "widgets/*.zip" file and configured developer account and also installed "CPDeveloper.sig" file into the TV.

So once we sync up the TV, it shows up our application name and progress bar then it stucks, after certain interval it goes off and we don't find our application anywhere into installed application list.

Any suggestion what are we doing wrong ?

Regards

Comment: Try to test your apps on RTS (http://rts.samsungdforum.com/) if it's still happened then somewhere in your code is the problem, but if it's not then it's your device. Try to upgrade to latest firmware first

Answer (score 1):

Also I would add a point to @andrea-f's answer.
Make sure **you dont have any javascript error** before this line:

> widgetAPI.sendReadyEvent();

If there is any error found before execution of this line then the application does not start.
This occurred to me once and I was really mad. But after verifying everything I got this issue.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers:

1. Make sure there are no errors in your `config.xml`, ie all tags closed all relevant tags present. [Sample config.xml](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/art00011/index.html#writing-the-config-xml-file)
2. Make sure the zip has the same name as the widget name in config.xml and the zipped files are already index.html etc and not in a subfolder
3. Check that app size matches size in widgetinfo.xml
4. You don't need the signature file if you only upload apps using app sync, signature file is necessary only if you load apps from USB.
5. Make sure the app size is smaller than the available space on the device.
6. Check that you can download the app from another device using the browser and the connection doesn't drop.
7. Make sure you don't load any JS from http but only locally.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue with the widgetlist.xml file.  Load that file in an xml viewer and check that the xml syntax is correct.  The TV does not return an informative error if the xml syntax is wrong.  It hangs, or reports a network error.

Also confirm that your zip file name is correctly listed in widgetlist.xml.  For example, has the date part of the name been updated by app packaging?  If so, you need to update your xml file for the new name.

As was noted in other replies, check that the widget id in the xml file matches the widget name in the config.xml and the name encoded in the name of the zip file.

I have not personally needed to change the app size to match the zip file size.  I've been using:

```
 <compression size="28316793" type="zip" />
```

for everything on a 2013 tv.

Checking that the widgetlist.xml can be loaded in the browser of a different system, and checking the available space on your tv are also excellent ideas suggested in another answer.

The main point to keep in mind is that the error message from the tv for loading problems is uninformative, even misleading. So, check everything.

If everything looks good, reconnect your tv to the network and login again, and then retry.